# Sending number instead of string from Select in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a **"controlled"** React component for a very simple drop down that looks like this:

```
const MyDropDown = ({field, handleChange}) => {

   return(

      <select name="myField" value={field} onChange={handleChange}>
         <option value="1">Apples</option>
         <option value="2">Oranges<option>
         <option value="3">Bananas</option>
      <select>
   );
}

MyDropDown.propTypes = {
   field: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
   handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default MyDropDown;
```

Initially, I set the value of the `field` to `0` in my reducer. This is the right thing to do because the value will always be a number. The problem I'm having is this:

Initially, everything is fine but when I make a selection, I get a warning saying an invalid prop of type string is supplied and it was expecting a number.

How do I make sure the values in the options are numbers and not strings?

BTW, I tried not using quotes for option values but React doesn't seem to like it i.e. `<option value=1>Apples</option>`

Comment: Just a suggestion, does `value={1}` work?

Comment: I just thought of that myself and tried it but still getting the same warning. It's still treating it as a string and not a number.

Comment: okay i assume field is a state in a hierarchically higher component, which is set in the handleChange-function. Maybe you need to parse the value to a number before setting that state?

Comment: You're exactly right! @teaflavored just gave me the same answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume your handleChange looks something like this

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ val: e.target.value});
}
```

The issue here is that html needs quotes around the attribute values, so in essence e.target.value resolves to a string. A simple fix would be to parse it into a number by using

```
parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
```

Comment: For those who don't know the second parameter of the parseInt function is radix. For decimal numbers, radix must be equal to 10.

Answer (score 4):

if your handler looks like above you can use `+e.target.value`